# Pi and the sum of reciprocals of primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

So I know that $$\sum_{\underset{\Large p\; prime}{p=1}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p}$$
blows up. But doing some fun on mathematica I found out that when the sum isn't infinite, it was so close to $3$ and I conjectured that there exists an $\epsilon$ such that $$\sum_{\underset{\Large p\; prime}{p=1}}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{p}=\pi$$
Is this conjecture true or false and more importantly why?

Comment: A more interesting question for you to work on is whether there is an infinite subsequence of the primes such that when you add the reciprocals of the primes in that subsequence, you indeed get $\pi$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Do you have the answer to that question? It seems to be very interesting!

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Yes, it is a nice observation: If you have a sequence of positive numbers that converges to zero and such that their associated series diverges, then for every real $r$ there is a subsequence whose series adds up to exactly $r$. (And for much more general results, there is a nice recent survey of the possibilities of the set of sums of subsequences of a given sequence, [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3779).)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think a fun thing you should investigate is the sum of the reciprocals of twin prime pairs. Believe it or not, it converges! It converges to a value known as *Brun's Constant*, namely  $ 1.902160583104\ldots$

Comment: With some extra research, I discovered that Brun's Constant is actually suggested to be $\approx  1.902160583\ldots$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, since if that sum were finite, i.e $n\in\mathbb N$  $$\dfrac{1}{p_1}+\dfrac{1}{p_2}+\dfrac{1}{p_3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{p_n},$$
then we can express it as: $a/b$ $(a,b\in\mathbb N)$ which is rational, unlike $\pi$.

Comment: i don't understand, isn't $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ irrational and according to your claim it should be rational?

Comment: @user149842 That sum doesn't meet the condition I mentioned at first, and that is: **the sum is finite**. Since an infinite series can be an irrational number.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

It's false. $\pi$ is irrational, while the finite sum of rationals is rational.

Comment: You should mention: *"the **finite** sum of rationals is rational"*, since an infinite sum of rationals can be irrational, example: $\pi=3+0.1+0.04+\cdots$

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, the finite sum would be rational. Actually this idea gives an amusing proof that there must be infinitely many prime numbers. Suppose that there are only finitely many prime numbers. Then we have $\pi^2/6=\zeta(2)=\prod_{p}\frac{1}{1-1/p^2}$, which would be rational. Hence $\pi^2$ would be rational. This is a contradiction.